# Doctrine relation betwen two tables

Tags: doctrine, entity-relationship

I have two tables A and B. A have one or more registers in B. 
I want to join two tables and extract all information about A.

I do that:

Schema.yml

```
A:
  fields.....

B:
  fields...
  relations:
    A: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: a.id, foreign: b.id, foreignalias: AB }
```

And i try to do that...

```
  $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('A a')
  ->leftJoin('a.AB b')
  ->where('a.field = "D"')
  ->andWhere('b.codzon = ?', $this->cp);
```

It prints me error: **Unknown relation alias AB**
What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have one-to-many relation?

Comment: yes darmen, i have a one-to-may relation and another many-to-many.
i read vladimir link but i don't understant the way many-to-many do relationship... above all this:


 relations:
    Users:
      foreignAlias: Groups
      class: User
      refClass: GroupUser

why group entity need to have relation with user if there are an entity called usergroup???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query seems to be ok, errors are in you sheme definition. You need to define relations on both sides: A and B. I am not very comfortable with YML, but it should look like this:

```
A:
  relations:
    B:
      local: id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: AB
      foreignType: many
      type: one
```

See also http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/ru/yaml-schema-files#relationships:one-to-many for detect_relations option.

Comment: i don't understand what is differerent in my one to may definition and the one-to-many in the web you write..

Answer (score 0):

Remove table names from schema:

```
...
A: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: id, foreign: id, foreignalias: AB }
...
```

Comment: darmen, its a mistake writing it. in my schema definition i don't have a. and b.
thanks